# Passing DateTime to ASP.net Core API (DateTime model binding)

Tags: asp.net-core, data-binding, .net-core, asp.net-web-api2

I have the following controller action in .NetCore which gets an object from MyModel class:

```
[HttpPut]
public PutAsync([FromBody] MyModel model){
....
}

public class MyModel{
   DateTime FromDate { get; set; }
   ...
 }
```

and I call REST PUT method by passing the following JSON body:

```
{
  "FromDate":"02.12.2017",...
}
```

It throws an exception:

> "After parsing a value an unexpected character was encountered: \". Path 'FromDate', line 5, position 1."

**How should I write a proper model binding for DateTime which is located inside a model input class?**

Comment: The JSON body that your putting seems fine and so does your C# model. Could you please also post the client-side code that is making the put. That will help with the troubleshooting.

Comment: I put a demo here for you: https://github.com/shaunluttin/asp-net-core-webapi-fetch

Comment: Where did you get this error? Change `DateTime FromDate { get; set; }` to `        public DateTime FromDate { get; set; }`. Share us a reproduceable project.